# How to check if a field has an annotation when using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using reflection so I can check if some fields in another class have annotations.

DummyUser class:

```
package com.reflec.models;

public class DummyUser {

@NotNull
private String firstName;

private String lastName;

@NotNull
private String email;

public DummyUser() {

}

public DummyUser(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DummyUser user = new DummyUser();

    List<Field> list = seekFieldsWithAnnotations(user);         
    System.out.println("Size: " + list.size());
}

public static List<Field> seekFieldsWithAnnotations(Object o) {
    Class<?> clss = o.getClass();
    List<Field> fieldsWithAnnotations = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Field> allFields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(clss.getDeclaredFields()));
    for(final Field field : allFields ) {
        if(field.isAnnotationPresent((Class<? extends Annotation>) clss)) {
            Annotation annotInstance = field.getAnnotation((Class<? extends Annotation>) clss);
            if(annotInstance.annotationType().isAnnotation()) {
                fieldsWithAnnotations.add(field);
            }
        }
    }
    //clss =  clss.getSuperclass();
    return fieldsWithAnnotations;
}
```

If I get the size of the list that is returned by `seekFieldsWithAnnotations`,  the size is always 0. When actually I was expecting it to be 2 because the fields `firstName` and `email` have annotations above them.

If I return the `allFields` list and get its size I get back 3 because there are three fields in the `DummyUser` class.

So I think the place where I am going wrong is

```
for(final Field field : allFields ) {
    // Here I am trying to check if annotations are present
    if(field.isAnnotationPresent((Class<? extends Annotation>) clss)) {
        Annotation annotInstance = field.getAnnotation((Class<? extends Annotation>) clss);
        if(annotInstance.annotationType().isAnnotation()) {
            fieldsWithAnnotations.add(field);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using this code.

```
public static StringBuilder seekFieldsWithAnnotations(Object object) {
    Class<?> c = object.getClass();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Field[] fieldsArr = c.getDeclaredFields();
    List<Field> allFields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fieldsArr));

    for(Field field : allFields) {
        if(field.getDeclaredAnnotations().length > 0) {
            Annotation[] fieldAnnots = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();

            sb.append("Field Name: " + field.getName() + "\nAnnotations: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < fieldAnnots.length; i++) {
                if(fieldAnnots.length == 1 || fieldAnnots.length - i == 1) {
                    sb.append(fieldAnnots[i].toString() + "\n\n");
                } else {
                    sb.append(fieldAnnots[i].toString() + ", ");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("\"" + field.getName() + "\" has no annotations.\n");
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call [getDeclaredAnnotations()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getDeclaredAnnotations()) in order to fetch **all** declared annotations for each of the fields. The javadoc also makes it very clear that you are using `getAnnotation()` in the wrong way. This method expects you to pass an **annotation class**; but you are passing the class of the enclosing object to it.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by @Jägermeister, you should use `getDeclearedAnnotations`.

You can simplify your code as follows:

```
public static List<Field> seekFieldsWithAnnotations(Object o) {
    List<Field> fieldsWithAnnotations = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        Annotation[] declaredAnnotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        if (declaredAnnotations.length > 0) {
            fieldsWithAnnotations.add(field);
        }
    }
    return fieldsWithAnnotations;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but `getDeclaredAnnotations()` is not returning the anything at all. So `declaredAnnotations` ends up being null.